# How can I find the latest video on a Vimeo channel with JSON?

Tags: video, video-streaming, json, vimeo

I'm trying to embed in my page the latest video submitted to my Vimeo channel. I found the following documentation which helps http://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed, but I'm still unsure how to approach this - what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all of your data is **public**, you can use Vimeo's Simple Api.

The documentation for finding the videos in a channel is here : https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/simple#channel-request

Lets say you wanted to find the most recent video published to the VimeoHQ channel.

1. Pull down the JSON from `http://vimeo.com/api/v2/channel/vimeohq/videos.json`
2. Parse the JSON into an array
3. The newest video is the first element of the array
4. Use the "url" field with oembed to build your embed link.

If your data is **private** you will have to use [Vimeo's Advanced API](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced).

This method is a little more complicated, and requires you to use OAuth 1.0. I recommend you use an existing library, and explore the vimeo.channels.getVideos method.

Answer (score 3):

Just found this looking for a similar solution. It appears that Vimeo no longer offers its simple API. To accomplish something like this, you'll need to register as a developer and get a token. My understanding of the oEmbed API is that it requires you to provide the video ID, which means you'd have to already know it. I don't think the oEmbed API will allow you to do what the original question is asking; but, I'd love to be proven wrong!

Here's the new [Vimeo developer portal](https://developer.vimeo.com/).